# Unable to save Ordering to database - Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and within it i am trying to save Ordering of list by first drag and drop to re-order and the click save to save the reordering. however, the list does not get saved. any help would be appreciated.

**View File:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <section>
                <h2>Order Songs</h2>
                <p class="alert alert-info">Drag to order Songs and click 'Save'</p>
                <div id="orderResult"></div>
                <? echo form_button('save', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-default" id="save" value="Save"')?>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
$(function() {
        $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/songs/order_ajax'); ?>', {}, function(data){
                $('#orderResult').html(data);
        });

        $('#save').click(function(){

                oSortable = $('.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray');

                $('#orderResult').slideUp(function(){
                        $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/songs/order_ajax'); ?>', { sortable: oSortable }, function(data){
                                $('#orderResult').html(data);
                                $('#orderResult').slideDown();
                        });
                });

        });
});
</script>
```

**order_ajax File:**

```
<?php
echo get_ol($songs);

function get_ol ($array, $child = FALSE)
{
        $str = '';

        if (count($array)) {
                $str .= $child == FALSE ? '<ol class="sortable">' : '<ol>';

                foreach ($array as $item) {
                        $str .= '<li id="list_' . $item['id'] .'">';
                        $str .= '<div>' . $item['songname'] .'</div>';

                        // Do we have any children?
                        if (isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])) {
                                $str .= get_ol($item['children'], TRUE);
                        }

                        $str .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
                }

                $str .= '</ol>' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        return $str;
}
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
        handle: 'div',
        items: 'li',
        toleranceElement: '> div',
        maxLevels: 2
    });

});
</script>
```

**The Controller:**

```
public function order() {
    $data['sortable'] = TRUE;
    $data['title'] = 'Re-Order';
    $data['module'] = 'admin';
    $data['header_file'] = 'admin_header';
    $data['nav_file'] = 'admin_nav';
    $data['view_file'] = 'song_order';
    $data['script_file'] = 'admin_script';
    echo Modules::run('template/template_admin', $data);
}

public function order_ajax() {
    // Save order from ajax call
    if (isset($_POST['sortable'])) {
        $this->mdl_admin_songs->save_order($_POST['sortable']);
    }

    // Fetch all pages
    $data['songs'] = $this->mdl_admin_songs->get_nested();

    // Load view
    $this->load->view('song_order_ajax', $data);
}
```

**The Model:**

```
public function get_nested() {
    $songs = $this->db->get('songrequest')->result_array();

    $array  = array();
    foreach ($songs as $song) {
        if (!$song['parent_id']) {
            $array[$song['id']] = $song;
        }
        else {
            $array[$song['parent_id']]['children'][] = $song;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

public function save_order($songs) {
    if (count($songs)) {
        foreach ($songs as $order => $song) {
            if ($song['item_id'] != '') {
                $data = array('parent_id' => (int) $song['parent_id'], 'order' => $order);
                $this->db->set($data)->where($this->_primary_key, $song['item_id'])->update($this->_table_name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Have you tried debugging to work out the issue? Does the post line get executed? Is it received at the controller?

Comment: i dont think the controller is receiving the post data. that is the problem.

Comment: Is it because it isn't being posted or it's being posted incorrectly? Are you now debugging this further?

Comment: I have to admit that i am a noob and very new to this. Thats why i do need help.

Comment: OK so.... I can't work out whether you need any more help or not. Establish for certain whether or not it's being posted and post more info. Or ask for more specific information.

Comment: ok... the thing is when i click on post the data is to be updated to the database. the result which i  need. when i do a var_dump of the post data on click... i get NULL. i am not sure why i get this. all i need to do is to reorder the rows of the table and save the reorder to the database.

Comment: You need to break it into pieces and find out where it's breaking down. Learn to use the F12 tools (press F12 in the browser) and that will elt for example observe code running, observe what is being posted. If NULL is being posted then there must be some issue in your javasript or form so th enext step is to use F12 to step through your javascript code and observe if it's posting anything.

Comment: Thanks Nick...  will surely check and update.